# How can I manage my time with Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, plugins, time-management

I wasn't a big fan of Microsoft Office until now, but my boss has told me that I have to use Outlook in order to manage my time. I really don't know why the Outlook is a powerful tool.

Now I use email functions,  the calendar and the to do list. Can you recommend me some useful free addons in order to use Outlook in time management?

Many thanks

Comment: Meaningless title, not really a question.

Comment: I changed the title, but I seriously doubt why you would want this only for Outlook. You just need A time management system that's possibly free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does it have to be Outlook? If he doesn't tell you what function to use, just use A method of managing your time.

I looked on Stackoverflow what questions they had on this over there:

- [What’s the best way to track and submit a timesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108066/whats-the-best-way-to-track-and-submit-a-timesheet#108079)
- [How do you track your hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707/how-do-you-track-your-hours)
- [Time management tricks, tools & tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273/time-management-tricks-tools-tips)

I would personally recommend [Timesnapper](http://www.timesnapper.com/), it seems to do what you ask in a fairly good fashion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. I sync my Outlook appointments with the calendar on my cell phone. That way, I get a warning chime on my phone, and never miss an appointment even if I'm away from my computer.
2. If you are using [Onenote](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote/default.aspx), then your ToDos in Onenote will appear as ToDos in Outlook, and a reminder will pop up when the assignment is due.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook has a Tasklist, where you can specify which tasks you're working on, when the task needs to be finished, your current progress with this task and (in the details) the number of hours that you've spent on this and you can assign others to help you with the same task!

It's not the most practical solution, but if it's the one your Boss wants you to use, fine. Do what I did: add a task which tells the amount of time it takes you to add tasks.